# How do I get the nausea effect command in Minecraft 1.14.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I get the nausea effect command in Minecraft 1.14.2? I know there's some commands for older versions of Minecraft but none of them seem to work for the latest version...

Answer (score 4):

It really isn't hard to figure out. The syntax has changed since 1.12, but it still has the same concept. The command looks something like this:

```
/effect give|clear <playerName> <effect> <time> <amplifier>
```

You can either give or clear effects by typing `give` or `clear`. Next, you put in your username. Next is the ID. Instead of typing numbers, a name ID is required (`minecraft:<effectName>`). Last is amount of time the effect will last (in seconds) and it's amplifier (effect level).

Let's say we want to give the effect to a player named jenny, and we want the nausea effect for 10 seconds without amplifiers. The command will look like this:

```
/effect give jenny minecraft:nausea 10 0
```

A full-length guide on using the `/effect` command can be found [here](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/effect_command.php), and the list of possible effects and their IDs can be found [here](https://www.digminecraft.com/lists/effect_list_pc.php).